# Use ws for send messages to a discord bot

Tags: websocket, discord.js, ws

I use ws module to send messages from my discord.js bot to my website, but how can I do the opposite?

Here the line to connect the bot with the website:

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1450", ["wamp"]);
```

I define WebSocket here:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
```

I need to insert an url (is a mandatory parameter) instead of

```
ws://localhost:1450
```

What should I put?

P.S I use Heroku to host it (I don't know if it's useful information)

Comment: websockets are omnidirectional, you can send messages through the same socket you use to transmit data from the bot to the website. Maybe read up on the client-server model?

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about WebSockets is that it's a connection that makes information travel both ways, but it's usually used when the server wants to send something. Another famous protocol is [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview): in reinforces the idea of server and client. The client asks something (HTTP request), and the server answers (HTTP response).
I think that HTTP would be much more appropriate than sockets in your use case.

Since you're using Node.js, you should build an [Express](https://expressjs.com/fr/) server to host an API and create endpoints that your bot will fetch each time it receives a message. If you feel lost, no worries! I did too while starting with Express, but you'll see, it's fairly easy. I don't know if it will be of any help to you, but [this video](https://youtu.be/vjf774RKrLc) really helped me in the beginning, maybe you should watch it.

Anyways, go check out the HTTP protocol, I'm sure it'll be easier than to work with WebSockets.